# Color row based on change in (previous row) cell value

Tags: excel, vba, colors, row

I'm trying to write a code that will automatically change the color of each row based on a (text) value in Column B. So start with a (customer) name the rows are white, next name is blue, next one is white again etc. So far I have not even come close to a solution.

So far I have tried:

Conditional formatting (MOD or REST) function.

All kinds of code (like this one, written by chatGPT):

```
Private Sub Underline()

Dim rng As Range
Dim rrow As Range
   
' Define the range where you want to apply the alternating row colors
Set rng = Range("A2:AE200") ' Adjust the range as per your requirements

' Initialize variables
Dim prevName As String
prevDate = 1 - 1 - 1900
   

' Loop through each row in the range
For Each rrow In rng.Rows
    ' Check if the row is visible and not part of a filtered row
    If rrow.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        If rrow.Cells(1, 3).Value <> prevDate Then
                'Underline
                Range("A" & Selection.Row & ":AE" & Selection.Row).Select
                With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
                End With
            'reset the comparison value
            prevDate = rrow.Cells(1, 3)
        End If
    End If
Next rrow
```

End Sub

This last one was were I added a column with True or false but I'd rather do without.

Comment: Can you show how your data looks like? Is the data sorted by customer? Can a customre appear more that once? And what is it about "ONWAAR" in your code? What does the code do, and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: @FunThomas "ONWAAR" is "FALSE" in Dutch. However, the way OP said he wanted to do it without that helper column. So I suppose it's just coloring each row alternating between blue/white depending on the name of the customer. Is there one line per customer or will there be multiple lines of the same customer (i.e. several lines of white  instead of alternating on the same customer)?

Comment: No need for code, you can do this with conditional formatting, but I wonder if `If cell.Cells(1, rng.Columns.Count).Value = false` would work.

Comment: I've read somewhere that KI will replace all programmers in the next 5 years. Way to go, I would say.

Comment: @FunThomas, I don't know what you did but this code does exactly what I want. Which is strange because I have not added the True/False column in my testfile?

Comment: I didn't do anything to your code except formatting it so that you can read it.

Comment: Forget that last comment, it only worked once.

Comment: Can i upload a test file or sreenshot somehow?

Comment: SJR, that does not take into account any hidden rows.

Comment: @Notus_Panda yes that is what I want the code to do. It could be one row of a customer but also ten or fifteen rows of the same customer.

Comment: To add a screenshot. edit your question (press "edit" below the tags), move to the place where you want to add the image and press the image icon on the command bar (above your text).

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rrow As Range
    Dim colorIndex As Integer
    
    ' Define the range where you want to apply the alternating row colors
    Set rng = Range("A2:AE200") ' Adjust the range as per your requirements
    
    ' Initialize variables
    colorIndex = 2 ' Start with white
    Dim prevName As String
    prevName = ""
    
    ' Loop through each row in the range
    For Each rrow In rng.Rows
        ' Check if the row is visible and not part of a filtered row
        If rrow.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            If rrow.Cells(1, 2).Value <> prevName Then
                'Toggle the colour
                colorIndex = IIf(colorIndex = 1, 2, 1)
                'reset the comparison value
                prevName = rrow.Cells(1, 2)
            End If
            rrow.Interior.Color = IIf(colorIndex = 1, RGB(255, 255, 255), RGB(0, 0, 255))
        End If
    Next rrow
End Sub
```

Essentially just flip the colours everytime the value in column B changes

Comment: I need to test it further, but so far it's perfect. Thank you!!

Comment: I don't want to push my luck, but there is also a Date column which needs to be underlined when the date changes. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @LeondeRuiter In the same subroutine you could use
`Intersect(Range("J1:J200"), Target).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle`

Comment: Hi Chill60 I'm sure that will do, but i am at a loss where to put it. The dates are in column C (3). And I don't mean to underline but border (xlDashDotDot) the row from A to AE?

Comment: this would go into the `Worksheet_Change` Sub. Instead of underlining the intersection you should go through the rows within the intersection and set the border for each - build the range based on `Range("A" &  row & ":AE" & row)`

Comment: Can you show me the full code? I've been at it for hours but no result.

Comment: If you edit your post to show the code you are using for that bit then I might be able to help

Comment: @LeondeRuiter - Please don't edit my solution. Edit your post to include your code.

Comment: this is what I got - it's crap i know....